# PHP JSON API - Not Having To Define Location Eveytime

Tags: php, json, api

Hello I made a JSON API using PHP. The only problem is, I need to define the location everytime. As it's quite a big API, this is nearly impossible and very tiring to do everytime.

The API is created like so:

```
            $api = array(
                array(
                    'store' => array(
                        array('name' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['name']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['name'] : ''),
                        array('skuid' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['default-sku-id']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['default-sku-id'] : ''),
                        array('releasedate' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['release-date']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['release-date'] : ''),
                        array('nonplusprice' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['skus'][0]['prices']['non-plus-user']['actual-price']['display']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['skus'][0]['prices']['non-plus-user']['actual-price']['display'] : ''),
                        array('psplusprice' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['skus'][0]['prices']['plus-user']['actual-price']['display']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['skus'][0]['prices']['plus-user']['actual-price']['display'] : ''),

                        array(
                            'filesize',
                            array('value' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['file-size']['value']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['file-size']['value'] : ''),
                            array('unit' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['file-size']['unit']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['file-size']['unit'] : ''),
                        ),

                        //...
                    )
                )

            return(json_encode($api));
```

Now when I want to use the values, I need to do this:

```
echo $json[0]['store'][1]['skuid']; // sku id
echo $json[0]['store'][4]['psplusprice']; // price
```

How do I change the API so I don't have to specify the location (e.g. for this example the 1 and the 4)?

Desired result:

```
echo $json[0]['store']['skuid']; // sku id
echo $json[0]['store']['psplusprice']; // price
```

Comment: Why not just remove inner arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try removing unnecessary levels like in this example:

```
<?php

            $api =[
                    ['store' => [
                        'name' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['name']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['name'] : '',
                        'skuid' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['default-sku-id']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['default-sku-id'] : '',
                        'releasedate' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['release-date']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['release-date'] : '',
                        'nonplusprice' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['skus'][0]['prices']['non-plus-user']['actual-price']['display']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['skus'][0]['prices']['non-plus-user']['actual-price']['display'] : '',
                        'psplusprice' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['skus'][0]['prices']['plus-user']['actual-price']['display']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['skus'][0]['prices']['plus-user']['actual-price']['display'] : '',
                        'filesize' => [
                            'value' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['file-size']['value']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['file-size']['value'] : '',
                            'unit' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['file-size']['unit']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['file-size']['unit'] : '',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                ];

    var_dump($api[0]['store']['skuid']);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right now is:

```
[..]
'store' => array(
    array('name' => 'Some name'),
//  ^ Why did you type this array here?
```

What you want to do is

```
[..]
'store' => array(
    'name' => 'Some name',
```

Thus

```
[..]
'store' => array(
    'name' => isset($store['included'][0]['attributes']['name']) ? $store['included'][0]['attributes']['name'] : '',
```

When using PHP 7.0 or higher, you can shorten that with the (new) [coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
[..]
'store' => array(
    'name' => $store['included'][0]['attributes']['name'] ?? '',
```